# Not able to read config properties values in decorator jsp file spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my context.xml file I have

```
  <bean id="applicationProperties"       
   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
       <list>
        <value>classpath:myFile.properties</value>
       </list>
     </property>    
   </bean>
```

and defined

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
          <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/>
          <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
            <list> 
             <value>applicationProperties</value>
            </list>
         </property>  
</bean>
```

By doing this I am able to read all the properties values in my view jsp, but my requirement is to read the property values in decorator jsps, which I am not able to do.

Can anyone suggest the solution.

Problem I am understanding is that we have exposed bean only to the jsps lying within (/WEB-INF/views/), but my decorator jsps are not within this path and that's the reason I am not getting these property to decorator jsp file.

Thanks,
bond